# How to point to current directory in serviceworker.js

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have my service worker installed on a staging directory

Main Website is on: `https:example.com`

Staging is on: `https:example.com/test/`

Service Worker path: `https:example.com/test/serviceworker.js`

This is how I register service worker:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('https:example.com/test/serviceworker.js', {scope: '/test/'})
.then(registration => {
  console.log(`Service Worker registered! Scope: ${registration.scope}`);
})
```

Service worker works just fine, and is installed.

**My concern is that inside serviceworker.js I want to use the `/` to point to the path of the current directory automatically, which is in this case: `/staging/`**

For example when I want to cache the homepage in my staging site

```
/**
 * Cache the homepage.
 */
workbox.routing.registerRoute('/', workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate();
```

Here its caching **`https:example.com`** not **`https:example.com/test/`**

I know I can simply change `registerRoute('/')` to `registerRoute('/staging/)'`

But that is not efficient, and will make me need to have different version of the serviceworker for localhost, staging, and deployment.
I want to know what's the right way to do it here, so I can set the scope '/' to the current directory that the serviceworker.js is in.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I figured how to do it the right way.

**How to point to current directory:** simply './' Instead of '/'

```
/**
 * Cache the homepage.
 */
workbox.routing.registerRoute('./', workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate();
```

**How to cache files and images in current path:** './image/' instead of '/image/'

```
const urlsToCache = [
  './image/fallback.png',
  './offline/'
];
```

Now the same file works the same locally and on staging.
This is such a newbie mistake, I need to be more clever :)

Edit:
I found this in [Google documentation (The Service Worker Lifecycle)](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#scope_and_control):

> The default scope of a service worker registration is ./ relative to
>   the script URL. This means if you register a service worker at
>   //example.com/foo/bar.js it has a default scope of //example.com/foo/.

Comment: Thanks, Kash. I had the exact same staging/production situation and that is indeed the solution. If you're not using Workbox, the homepage can be cached with `cache.put('./index.html', serverResponse.clone());`.

Answer (score -1):

in your case

you will need a flag to wether decide in the service worker registration if it's staging or production.

---

having the staging on a sub path of your production domain is not optimal at all.

Comment: No, you won't need a flag. That suggestion is not optimal ! See Kash's answer for the optimal solution.